# Use Android smartphone to record sound

Tags: microphone, recording, android

Would it be possible to use a smartphone (in my case a Nexus S) to record sound using an external microphone. I guess I could use an adaptor to connect the microphone to the audio jack and use the default voice recording app. Not sure if that would work though.

Any ideas on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure about the Nexus S, but I have an HTC Desire HD and have successfully done this with one of these: http://bit.ly/g9HckJ  (cheaper but functionally identical copies are available ;-)). Works pretty well, especially with this: http://soundcloud.com/apps/android

I wouldn't have thought the audio jack on the Nexus would be any different.

Good luck, HTH

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need an external mic

I recently used the app called Field Recorder from Google Play.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.pfitzinger.rec&hl=en

I am using a Samsung galaxy S4 and was blown away by it's feature.

The best thing is it allow you to record in stereo by using your mobile mic and the receiver (The part that press towards your ear)

Very minimal electronic static noise is produce by my phone itself can be capture and heard by it is very easy to eliminate it by using any DAW.

Here a video I created that I have capture it raw inside my bathroom

Check it out: https://youtu.be/4REwmJlQ8nE

Answer (score 0):

I've used two different devices to record audio on my Nexus S - http://amzn.com/B004XC6KHS and http://amzn.com/B005NZ05J8

The former is a mic, and will mute the speaker; the latter is designed to be used with any XLR or 1/4 inch audio input. Both will plug in to the audio jack and can be used by any audio recording app. I've used two, but don't have the links handy.